# How to get the item before the last item of an ArrayList in kotlin?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

How to get the item before the last item of an ArrayList in kotlin?

I  have a list like

```
val myList = listOf("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5")
```

I want to get "item4" from myList

Comment: `myList[myList.size - 2]`

Comment: Another one: `myList.takeLast(2).first()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myList[myList.lastIndex - 1]
```

be sure to check if there are at least two items in the array before calling this

---

EDIT:
If you're using this often, you can define an extension function that acts similarly to [`last()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html):

```
fun <T> List<T>.secondToLast(): T {
    if (size < 2)
        throw NoSuchElementException("List has less than two elements")
    return this[size - 2]
}
```

Comment: I just wrote an answer to point out the extension function. Great that you kept the out of range exception in mind. Removed mine.

Comment: Don't think this solution is better... I would rather choose to get `null` instead of an exception...

Comment: Depends on how you structure the rest of your code. No good or bad answer here.

Comment: Unless you cover all you work with collections in try-catch block this works... other than that this is a good example of a bad practice.

Comment: Not at all. Your code can be designed in such a way that you **never** get to call this method on a `List` that does not have at least two elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
myList.getOrNull(myList.lastIndex - 1)
```

This will not require additional checks, but will return `null` if the list is small or empty.

Additionally, as was mentioned in the comments you can use elvis operator to fall back to some other value or scenario:

```
myList.getOrNull(myList.lastIndex - 1) ?: "unknown"
```

or

```
myList.getOrNull(myList.lastIndex - 1) ?: return
```

Also for this use case, you can use `.getOrElse` function where you can choose fallback scenario based on the requested index:

```
myList.getOrElse(myList.lastIndex - 1) { index ->
    // todo:
}
```

Comment: This is extra useful if there's a chance of the list being too small; if it is, the elvis operator could be used to fall back to something else

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
myList.dropLast(1).lastOrNull()
```

This is not very efficient but it reads really nice.

Marko proposed a similar, more efficient way in the comments:

```
myList.takeLast(2).firstOrNull()
```

Comment: Better `lastOrNull()`

Comment: Well, basically this solution is not the best one regarding performance. It will, in fact, copy all of the list items except for the last one into a new list, which may introduce considerable overhead when repeated multiple times on a large list.

Comment: If you started from the opposite end (`takeLast`), you'd eliminate this unbounded overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I added your suggestions @MarkoTopolnik and hotkey